# Parse error when creating menu item layout in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla

Specifically, the chapter is about creating a new menu layout and the example uses the registration form.  Whenever I try to create a new menu item with the alternate registration form through the admin, I get the following error:

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): file:///C:/xampp/.../com_users/registration/approval.xml:23: parser error : error parsing attribute name in C:\xampp...\menutypes.php on line 395

I get this error and a few other similar ones, they all seem to blow up on line 395 of the mentioned file.  That line is:

```
if ($xml = simplexml_load_file($file))
```

how can I fix this?  Thanks!!

Comment: should have said I am using joomla 3.1.5

Comment: Never mind... like some work mates used to tell me, Intel inside, idiot outside. :-)  I was leaving out a whole line of code on my xml file.  It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess is that you should be using a [comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) instead of an [assignment operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php):

```
if ($xml == simplexml_load_file($file))
```